# jQuery click binding in a KnockoutJS foreach doesn't work

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

I have a jQuery click binding within a knockoutJS foreach, and it's not working.
I believe that knockout is stopping the propagation.

Is there a way to make it work?
I'm trying to avoid binding to click event with knockout.

Comment: Can you post some code? Maybe in a JSFiddle? By the way you should `return true` in your KO event handler to propagate the event.

Comment: if you don't share your code it's going to be difficult to help you

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Without seeing any of the code, I can only assume that you are doing something similar to

```
$('element').on('click', function(e){});
```

To bind a click event to dynamically generated objects you need to have your click events like this

```
$('body').on('click', 'element', function(e){});
```

Comment: Dynamic, of course :) You are correct. I used $(elem).live("click" , function(e){}); Instead of $(elem).click(function(e){});

Comment: ah gawd that is annoying. Why don't they just stop propagation when you used the KO click binder? And jquery.live is now deprecated. Using the jquery.on() and attaching to root worked for me.